# What does the phrase "application-by-application basis" mean?

Tags: wpf, software-design

I met the mentioned phrase here at [WPF: Styling and Templating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) styling and templating refer to a suite of features (styles, templates, triggers, and storyboards) that allow developers and designers to create visually compelling effects and to create a consistent appearance for their product.
>
> Although developers and or designers can customize the appearance extensively on an **application-by-application basis**, a strong styling and templating model is necessary to allow maintenance and sharing of the appearance within and among applications. Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) provides that model.
>   ...

I have never met this phrase and have no resource for it meaning.

I would like to know what this basis is.

Answer (score 1):

Application-by-application

You write one application and customize the appearance extensively.
You write another application and customize the appearance extensively.
....

Basis is what ever basis you wanted to use for customizing the appearance.

Is English not a first language for you?  That is a common phrase.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a software engineering term. The phrase "on an application-by-application basis" means "for each individual application".

*for example marketing on a client-by-client basis" means analyzing sale options for each individual client separately.*